# Почему C# так генерирует исключения?

Tags: c#

Я буду именовать блоки когда по номеру, который они выводят.
Как я понимаю, в блоке '**2**', мы явно не указываем тип исключения, то есть результат работы программы должен быть `1 2 3 5 6`, а на самом деле имеем `1 2 3 4 6`. Почему так?
Исключение из блока '**1**' мы уже обработали в '**2**', а в '**2**' у нас уже не `NullReferenceException`, а просто `throw`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("1");
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("2");
                throw; // интересует это
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("3");
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("4");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("5");
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("6");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `в '2' у нас уже не NullReferenceException, а просто throw` Что  значит `просто throw`?

Comment: Какой тип исключения, интересно, вы ожидаете в п. 5?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я так понимаю, это самый общий тип, туда попадают все исключения, чей тип мы более конкретно не указали

Comment: @tym32167 В смысле, без аргументов. Сейчас более-менее разобрался, зачем это нужно

Comment: В эту ветку — да, попадут все исключения, не перехваченные выше. Но какой конкретный тип исключения? (ex.GetType() что вернет?) Система же не может взять и на ровном месте бросить исключение какого-то случайного типа. `throw;` как вам написали в ответе просто перевыбросит то исключение, которое и было изначально

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw перебрасывает исключение, пойманное в catch так, как будто бы catch его не поймал. В вашем случае throw бросает то же исключение (тот же объект), что был пойман - т.е. брошенный выше NullReferenceException.